# Upload large video files using moss

Tags: sharepoint, http, iis, iis-7, sharepoint-2007

Im using share point 2007 over IIs 7.5.
While trying to upload a video file to the SharePoint (size 160MB), Im getting 404. 
Moreover, I created my own UploudFile custom Fiel in order to save the video files into a streaming server (and avoid saving it into the sharepoint server), but i can't get into my code in debug mode - the 404 accures before it's get to my code.

I tried to change the MaxUploadSize of the web application to 200 MB in the Web application general settings.

Should I change something in the IIS settings? Is there a problem of time out or somethig?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepointcomic/archive/2010/02/14/uploading-large-files-to-sharepoint-on-windows-server-2008-and-iis7.aspx) is the issue you are running into: